# Disabling loggers if No handlers are present

Tags: python-2.7, object, logging

I'm creating a python script and class object that passes logging handlers into the latter. The handlers are created using the *logging* class like so:

```
#Debug Handler
debug_handler = logging.FileHandler('Debug.log')
debug_handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

#Info Handler
info_handler = logging.FileHandler('Normal.log')
info_handler.setLevel(logging.INFO)
```

These handler objects are passed directly into the object initializer:

```
def __init__(self, type, path, info_handler = False, debug_handler = False):

    #Establishes Class Logger
    self.logger = logging.getLogger('LoggerName')
    self.logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    if (info_handler):
        self.logger.addHandler(info_handler)
    if (debug_handler):
        self.logger.addHandler(debug_handler)
```

My goal is to make the handlers completely **optional** for the object class, but to use them I must scatter calls across the code as frequently as print statements. Ex:

```
self.logger.info('INITIALIZING RESULTS OBJECT')
```

Which means that it will error should no handlers be passed. How can I manage/nullify these statements without placing try/catch on every single call in the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: There should be no issue with calling a logger when no handlers are present. The library simply prints out a statement acknowledging the lack of a handler. My error was caused by trying to add a handler that was not defined, and this was easily rectified by the statement below:

```
if (info_handler):
    self.logger.addHandler(info_handler)
if (debug_handler):
    self.logger.addHandler(debug_handler)
```

I'll leave this question up to show basic syntax for the logging library.